# Add user to group to specific database does not work

Tags: django, django-models

I am struggling to make the following code works for me.

```
user = User.objects.using(data[‘db_name’]).get(pk=1)
group = Group.objects.using(data[‘db_name’]).get(pk=2)
user.groups.add(group)
```

I can see that Django creates one record to auth_user_groups in the default database but not in the data[‘db_name’]) database. Interestingly, user and group objects are coming from data[‘db_name’] database.

Can anyone advise me how to add new record to data[‘db_name’] database successfully?